# My supervisor blocks the submission of my paper to a journal

Tags: publications, advisor, ethics, authorship

From the start of my PhD (applied mathematics), I had many disagreements with my supervisor on the research topic (no funding) she gave me. This made our relationship bad and collaboration unpleasant. In the last year before my thesis defense, I asked for a separation, but she was against that. Then, I stopped doing research with her earlier than the expected time, and started writing my PhD thesis, which was approved by the department. This annoyed my supervisor apparently, and now she is very slow in giving me feedback on my PhD thesis.

After submitting my thesis for defense, I extracted a paper out of the thesis, co-authored with my supervisor. She has agreed to revise it and then to submit it to a journal, however, she has held  the paper for more than one month, without any comment. I write emails to her several times for appointments, but she does not reply. I have a feeling that she did it on purpose as she wants to make my academia life after PhD difficult.

Is it an ethical issue to hold a student’s paper like this? I need the paper to apply for post-doc. In such a case, if the student insists to submit a paper to a journal, is there any ethical problem?

Comment: _I asked for a separation, but she was against that. Then, I stopped doing research with her earlier than expected time._ Why did you not find another supervisor?

Comment: This question has so many inconsistencies. "In my last second year". What is "last second year"? Any serious math PhD would require at least 3-5 years. "stopped doing research with her earlier than expected time and started writing my PhD thesis". So, your advisor did not approve your thesis? And you still got a PhD, despite of that? That makes no sense.

Comment: I downvoted the question because there are many inconsistencies. pointed out by @Alexandros and me. Please explain those inconsistencies and I would be more than happy to vote to re-open the question.

Comment: @Alexandros *So, your advisor did not approve your thesis? And you still got a PhD, despite of that? That makes no sense.* – The question says nothing about the asker having finished their PhD (I assume that the thesis is still under review) or the supervisor awarding a failing grade (she just disapproved of its early submission). But even if the supervisor wants the thesis to fail by all means, the rest of the department may be able to let it pass (which would be unusual, but apparently the department sides with the asker here). That being said, a bit more information would be helpful.